# Can't execute files with php-cron-scheduler

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to config "peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler" library and work with him in localhost, but can't execute a php file:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use GO\Scheduler;

$scheduler = new Scheduler();
$scheduler->php('cronTest.php')->everyMinute(1)->output('my_file.log');

//$scheduler->call(function () {
//    echo "Hello";
//    
//    return " world!";
//})->output('my_file.log')->everyMinute(1);

$scheduler->work();
```

The commented code work fine, generate correctly my_file.log, but when I try to execute php file, nothing happens.. I try with other Paths.

cronTest.php:

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
    <?php 
    
    return "Hello";
    
    ?>
```

Comment: You need to put the path/file not a url. Also in the script your probly going to need the full path to the file your reading. And make sure the file is writeable by the user. At the top of your script you will need #!/usr/bin/php and make the script executable.

Comment: Yes, I try with the path, but not work. Added #!/usr/bin/php And simplify the dile code, only with a return = "hello". But my_file not is created.

Comment: You can only return from a function. The program is errorring out. Have you run the script from the cli yet? Under the user that will be running the scheduling script?